# Can we install two kernel on same hardisk and on same partition?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have a single hard disk. It has 6 partition and on the 6th partition i have installed 
Linux kernel-3.10.26 .

Linux kernel-3.10.26 -> (hd0,sda6)

**Now i want to ask whether can i install another Linux kernel version say version 3.2.54 on same partition of same hard disk where previous version of Linux has been installed** and i can make a choice at boot time that in which version i should boot?

Linux Kernel-3.2.54 -> (hd0,sda6)

Comment: This depends on the bootloader you are using. Are you using grub, LILO, U-Boot, something else? Assuming that you are running on x86 with grub, you can install as many kernels as you wish, see http://superuser.com/questions/208502/how-to-add-a-new-kernel-to-grub2

Comment: @nitin Which Flavour of Linux you are using ? redhat, ubuntu....

Comment: @max Debian Xfce

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. Exactly how to do it will depend on your distro - if you want a version that's not in the repository, you might need to build it yourself. For example, [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) for Ubuntu.

Your bootloader will allow you to choose the kernel you want to boot.